# Does += return the value of the left hand side after assignment?

Tags: c

What does the C standard (preferably C89,90) say about:

```
int a,b;
a = 4;
b = (a += 1);
```

?

I have tested it and the result is `b=5`, which is what I expect. I just want to be reassured by the Standard. The same applies to analogous operators like `*=`, `/=`, `&=`, etc. I know that `=` is sure to return the value of the left hand side after the assignment. I just want to know if `+=`, `*=`, etc. behave the same way, according to the standard.

Comment: It doesn't matter which side you return. They're the same.

Comment: In C++ for a non-POD type, it'll call the assignment operator. So anything goes.

Comment: @Mysticial Depends on what you mean by right hand side in `a+=1`. Also, I want C, not C++. And I don't know what POD is...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assignment operators do not "return" a value: they yield one, or as the standard puts it, have one.

The value is of the left operand, although it won't be an lvalue. Here's the excerpt:

> (3.3.16) An assignment expression has the value of the left operand after the assignment, but is not an lvalue.

All of `=  *=  /=  %=  +=  -=  <<=  >>=  &=  ^=  |=` are assignment operators so they behave the same way in this regard.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a problem unless there are side-effects.

The assignment operator is not a sequence point, which means that there is no guarantee on order of evaluation.

If you use it as you have given (`b = (a += 1);`), it is not a problem.

However, in other cases, it may be a problem, for example:

```
b = (a += 1) + a; // undefined
```

Notice that in this example, the variable `a` is referred to twice. What that means is that we don't know whether `(a += 1)` or `a` is evaluated first. So we don't know if the 2nd reference to `a` will be before or after `1` was added to it.

If you only refer to each variable you assign with `+=` and co. once, then side-effects are not a problem, and you can count on `+=` and related operators to return the value **after** assignment.

Answer (score 0):

This should result in `b = 5` and `a = 5`.
This is because `a+=1` takes `a` and adds `1` to it. Then it assigns `a` to `b`.

I'm kind of confused on your question, but `*=`, `/=`, `-=` all work the same way.

For example, you could just have `int c = 7`; then on the next line do `c*=3`. This will make `c = 21`. If in your example, you didn't want `a = 5`; then just don't do `a+=1`, and instead, do `a+1`.